# Prove that $Lip [a,b]^{\circ}=\emptyset$

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Let $Lip[a,b]=\{f \in C[a,b] : \exists k>0,  |f(x)-f(y)|\leq k|x-y|\}$, Prove that $Lip[a,b]^{\circ}=\emptyset$ in $C[a,b]$.

Suppose there exists $f \in Lip[a,b]^{\circ}$, then $\exists \delta>0$: $B(f,\delta) \subset Lip[a,b]$. Now, I am trying to construct a function $g \in C[a,b] : g \in B(f,\delta)$ but for every $k>0$, there are $x,y$ : $|f(x)-f(y)|> k|x-y|$. Can anyone give me an idea on how to construct or find a function that satisfies this?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're using the supremum norm for $B(f,\delta)$, so find a function $\eta\in C[a,b]\backslash Lip[a,b]$ such that $\|\eta\|_\infty<\delta$ and consider $g=f+\eta$.   Hint for constructing $\eta$: oscillations.